# Obtengo error "campo id must have a value" en Delphi

Tags: delphi

Tengo un formulario:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y cuando hago click en el mas (+) del DBNavigator me dice:

**Field Id must have a value**

Id es el campo de la tabla de detalle de pedido. el DBNavigator esta conectado a un DataSource y este a un TClientDataSet el cual sus datos vienen de un provider y de un TSQLQuery.

En varios foros y temas en internet lei que debo setear la propiedad Required=False del campo id en el ClientDataSet y en el TSQLQuery.

De hecho ya lo hice y el problema desaparece pero no se guardan los cambios en la bd.

Y no se que deberia hacer.

Comment: Sin ningún código asociado, no veo la manera que hacer clic en el _[+]_, que hace un simple llamado al método `insert`, provoque este error. Esto podría ocurrir si tienes en edición el registro actual... y el error ocurriría como parte de la llamada a `post`, no a insert. Por tanto, también ocurriría al presionar el botón con la palomita.

Comment: Otra alternativa es que lo provoque el código en los eventos que puedan dispararse, en el data set, eeventos tales como `BeforeInsert`, `OnNewRecord`, en el datasource, eventos como `OnStateChange` (y otros). En ese caso, tu pregunta debiera incluir ese código, indicando la línea exacta que provoca el error.

Comment: La verdad no tengo nada programado en esos eventos. Pero bueno voy a probar usar querys para insercion y eliminacion.

Comment: El uso de queries para insertar y eliminar no hará que cambie este comportamiento. Como he dicho antes, la otra posible fuente del error es que el registro actual esté en edición al presionar el [+] ocurra durante el `post` del registro actual, y no durante la llamada al método `insert`. Podrías reproducir esto presionando el botón que tiene una palomita en el registro actual, y si es así, actualizar tu pregunta.